# Laravel - header/footer includes in views?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel, I would like to create my layout without using blade.

I have created a header.php view and a footer.php view.

In the filters.php file, I did this:

```
   App::before(function($request)
{
    return View::make('layout/top');
    //
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    return View::make('layout/bot');
    //
});
```

And in my routes:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

The header displays fine...but not the hello view or footer view.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should help (for Laravel 4): 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18105365/2661028

Answer (score 3):

Consider rendering your header and footer views to a variable, and then passing that to your content view. This also allows you to pass in extra data such as meta, js, styles, etc. that may be unique to the page your delivering to the DOM.

```
$data['header'] = View::make('templates/header')->render();
$data['footer'] = View::make('templates/footer')->render();
return View::make('myview', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `App::after` gets fired after the request: [application-events](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#application-events)

Myself, I use a single template (blade) which has a placeholder for content - You can use standard php in a blade template and this seams to give me more flexibility than controller layouts: [templating](http://laravel.com/docs/templates)