# Laravel 4 - including a "partial" view within a view (without using Blade template)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 3, I used to do this.

```
<?php render('partials.header'); ?>
```

This was done in "PHP" views, without using Laravel's Blade templates.

What's the equivalent of this in version 4?

I tried

```
<?php @include('partials.header'); ?>
```

This doesn't work.

If I do

```
@include('partials.header')
```

I have to save my file as ".blade.php"

How do I include a "subview" without using the blade template?

Comment: You can assign the child view to a variable of the parent view, using a view composer if the child is alywas to be loaded. Otherwise you need to go blade and use the templating system

Comment: so there is no immediate way to include "partial" PHP now?

Comment: I haven't used L4 yet, so I'm not really expert here, but browsing the docs I see nothing about. Anyway, I believe using the native include() outghta work, but you need to write a regular path, not a "laravel" path (i.e. use slashes not dots)

Comment: @ericbae could you please choose/mark the accepted answer :) thanks

Answer (score 24):

There are different ways to include a view within a view in Laravel 4. Your choice will depend on any one of the outcomes outlined below...

## For Flexibility

You can **compile (render)** the partial views in the appropriate Controller, and pass these views to the Main View using the `$data['']` array.

This may become tedious as the number of views increase, but hey, at least there's a lot of flexibility :)

See the code below for an example:

#### Controller

```
...

public function showMyView()
{
   /* Header partial view */
   $data['header'] = View::make('partials.header');

   /* Flexible enough for any kind of partial views you require (e.g. a Header Menu partial view) */
   $data['header_menu'] = View::make('partials.header_menu'); 

   /* Footer partial view */
   $data['footer'] = View::make('partials.footer');

   return View::make('myView', $data);
}

...
```

#### View

You can include the partials above as follows (at any position in your View code):

```
<html>  
<head></head>   
<body>

<!-- include partial views -->
<?php echo ($header) ?>  
<?php echo ($header_menu) ?>  

<div id="main-content-area"></div>  

<?php echo ($footer) ?>  

</body>  
</html>
```

Your partial views will now be added to your main View.

---

## For Simplicity

There's actually a much easier way than using the method above: Simply include this in the html of the view...

#### View

```
<html>  
<head></head>   
<body>

<!-- include partial view: header -->
<?php echo View::make('partials.header') ?>

   <div id="main-content-area">
   </div>

<!-- include partial view: footer -->
<?php echo View::make('partials.footer') ?>

</body>  
</html>
```

Make sure that the folder structure for the partials is **[views/partials/header.php]** in order to provide the correct file-path to the View::make() function of Laravel.

### WARNING

If you try to pass the `$data['page_title']` in a controller, the *nested views* wont receive the data.
To pass data to these nested views you need to do it like this:

```
<html>  
<head></head>   
<body>

<?php
   /* Pass page title to header partial view */
   $data ['page_title'] = "My awesome website";  
   echo View::make('partials.header', $data); 
?>

<div id="main-content-area"></div>

<?php echo View::make('partials.footer') ?>

</body>  
</html>
```

### NOTE

The question clearly stated: "Without using Blade template", so I have made sure to give a solution that does not include any Blade templating code.

## Good luck :)

Comment: Added the 'And rename header.php to header.blade.php' note!

Comment: This a bad practice, passing a data through views is not advisable.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24727043/1017298) for a different solution.

Comment: Is it not bad practice to do this way? <?php echo View::make('partials.footer') ?> Earlier I was told not to do this.

Answer (score 9):

You can nest your partials in views try this

```
View::make('folder.viewFile')->nest('anyname', 'folder.FileName');
```

Then access the nested view file from your template `{{ $anyname }}` this way you don't have to include files in your view and this should work for .php file also.

Comment: This solution uses Blade templates though (which the asker is trying to avoid)... 0.o

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure how many people have been using Laravel 4 in this post, since this post, but if you are looking to include partials or separate your view types you can do it with @includes

for example, if you want a partials folder for your header, footer, sidebar etc

create a directory for the partials under

```
app/views/partials
```

Then create a partial

```
app/views/partials/navigation.blade.php
```

Then in your master template file add the line

```
@include('partials.navigation')
```

That is all it takes.

** Bonus you can also pass data to a partial or include nested partials within a partial

Comment: `@include( 'partials.navigation', array( 'foo' => 'bar' ) )` to pass data to a partial

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit of a late answer, but I figured since I didn't see this solution amongst the other answers it was ok.

If you want to include your header and footer on every page I would add them into the before and after filters. Just go to filters.php in your app folder

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    echo View::make('partials.header');
});

App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    echo View::make('partials.footer');
});
```

When doing it this way you don't need to add anything in the view files to include them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use View's nest function

```
View::make('default.layout')->nest('header', 'default.header');
```

Use the third parameter to pass data to the template

```
View::make('default.layout')->nest('header', 'default.header', ['name' => 'John Doe', 'test' => 'It works!']);
```

on your views/default/header.blade.php

```
<div>hey {{ $name }}! {{ $test }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still pretty new to Laravel, but I think the below is pretty ideal ...

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $data['title'] = 'sample';
    return View::make('page', $data);
});

# /views/partials/header.php
# /views/partials/footer.php
View::composer('page', function($view)
{
    $view->with('header', View::make('partials.header', $view->getData()));
    $view->with('footer', View::make('partials.footer', $view->getData()));
});
```

See Laravel View Composers .. http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers

/views/page.php

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div>CONTENT</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: As Laravel5 has arrived so the above url will be http://laravel.com/docs/4.0/responses#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

From within a view, just echo the other view:

```
echo View::make('header'); //This will look for a view called header.php
```