# Laravel way to write re-usable view snippets

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have many models in my application. Each model has some specific markup that is used in countless locations. For instance, my `User` model has a `profile_link` attribute which is defined as follows:

```
class User extends Model {

    /*
     * Returns the anchor tag to the users profile.
     */
    public function getProfileLinkAttribute() {
        // This particular markup is simple. In the actual code, the HTML
        // is more complex, containing user's profile image etc.
        return '<a href="' . url($this->id) . '">' . $this->name . '</a>';
    }

}
```

There are many such accessors for many models, that return similar code snippets. The problem with this approach is that it makes me write HTML markup within the model. Is there any standard way to approach this?

Comment: You can explore `presenters`, this would allow you to have a `BasePresenter`. Other option also are html macros.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for in Laravel speak is ***View Partials***. These are reusable views that you include in other views. They can be included at the controller level or inside your view.

Here are some good links to get you started:

- [Laravel 4 - including a "partial" view within a view (without using Blade template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227969/laravel-4-including-a-partial-view-within-a-view-without-using-blade-templa)
- http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/90/including-a-blade-template-within-another-template
- https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/13